# Push a custom string in a SOQL result

Tags: apex, class

I'm not really sure if this is possible because i'm newbie but, can I push a custom string into a SOQL result?

I tried this code multiple times and i also modified it but i can't get the result i want:

```
List<Account> act = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]; 
String CmtTime = 'a_custom_string';
act.add(CmtTime);
```

then this one:

```
List<Account> clientResponse = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
String CmtTime= 'a_custom_string';
List<Account> clientRes = new List<Account>();
for(Account actItem : clientResponse){
    clientRes.add(CmtTime);
    clientRes.add(actItem);
}
```

I want to accomplish this result:

```
          Id         | Name  |      CmtTime
   0015D00000axxxxx  | test1 |   a_custom_string
   0015D00000bxxxxx  | test2 |   a_custom_string
   0015D00000cxxxxx  | test3 |   a_custom_string
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot, but you can create a wrapper object with the SOQL result.

```
public class Wrapper{
    Account accountObj; // {get;set;} if you need to use in VF page
    String customString; // {get;set;} if you need to use in VF page
    public Wrapper(Account accountObj, String customString){
        this.accountObj = accountObj;
        this.customString= customString;
    }
}
```

Use this wrapper class in your code.

```
List<Account> clientResponse = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
String CmtTime= 'a_custom_string';
List<Wrapper> clientRes = new List<Wrapper>();
for(Account actItem : clientResponse){
    clientRes.add(new Wrapper(actItem, 'a string here'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi Welcome to Salesforce!

Firstly create field as "CmtTime" in Account Object.

Once you create field in account you can use in query as field Api name as "CmtTime__c".
Remember here you have to use DML statement to update into database.

Here is how you can do

```
List<Account> clientResponse = [SELECT Id, Name,CmtTime__c FROM Account];
String CmtTime= 'a_custom_string';
for(Account actItem : clientResponse){
     actItem.CmtTime__c = CmtTime;
}
//DML statement to update account records. 
 update clientResponse;
```